# Dudas sobre ejecución de código python

Tags: python

Hola saludos a todos y gracias de antemano
Tengo este segmento de código que he creado pero tiene un problema en el método "repartir fihas" ahí recibo una lista de objetos del método "crear partida" a partir de ahí asigno aleatoriamente 7 de estos objetos a 4 "jugadores" una vez que creo el jugador y le asigno la lista todo bien cada jugador toma su lista bien pero cuando creo el arreglo de objetos "jugadoress" todos los jugadores reciben la misma lista, los nombres y todo lo demás bien pero la lista se repite para todos, no sé que está sucediendo. Gracias por al ayuda. Aquí envío el código.

```
import random


class ficha:
    def __init__(self, valor1, valor2):
        self.valor1 = valor1
        self.valor2 = valor2

class jugador:
    def __init__(self, idd, nombre, avatar, lista_fichas):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.idd = idd
        self.avatar=avatar
        self.lista_fichas=lista_fichas
                
def tirar (self):
    print("impleentar metodo de tirar")

class mesa:
    def __init__(self, color, plantilla):
        self.color = color
        self.pantilla = plantilla

class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad

class Juez:
    
def __init__(self):
    pass      

def informacion (self,integrante):

    self.integrante=integrante
    playeruno=[1,"Rolando","loco"]
    playerdos=[2,"Benzema","delantero"]
    playertres=[3,"Modric","medio"]
    playercuatro=[4,"Kroos","mediocentro"]

    listaplayer=[playeruno,playerdos,playertres,playercuatro]
    
    return listaplayer[self.integrante]

def crear_partida(self):
    lista_ficha_c=[]
    for i in range(0,7):
        for u in range (i,7):
            lista_ficha_c.append(ficha(i,u))
    return lista_ficha_c

def repartir_fihas (self):
    lista_aux=[None,None,None,None,None,None,None]
    jugadoress=[]  
    n = 28 # número de elementos que deseas seleccionar
    seq = range(28) # secuencia de elementos para elegir (en este caso, los números del 0 al 28)
    aleatorio=random.sample(seq, n)    
    lista=self.crear_partida()
    for u in range (0,4):
        
        for i in range (0,7):
            operacion=u*7+i
            lista_aux[i]=lista[aleatorio[operacion]]
            
        playeer=self.informacion(u)
       
        jugadoraux=jugador(playeer[0],playeer[1],playeer[2],lista_aux) #creo un objeto jugador con una lista de fichas
        jugadoress.append(jugadoraux) #creo un arreglo con 4 objetos del tipo jugador 
               
    return jugadoress

Juezuno=Juez()
verfichas=Juezuno.repartir_fihas()
```

Comment: Debes publicar un código ejecutable. El que publicas está incompleto (¿crear_partidas()?)

Comment: El error es que compartes la misma lista entre todos los jugadores. Debes crear una lista distinta para cada jugador.

Comment: Si hubieras publicado un código completo, te daría una respuesta mostrando la solución.

Comment: Hola he actualizado la pregunta con el código completo. gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema es creas `lista_aux` una vez y luego la asignas a cada jugador. Cada jugador guarda **no** la lista sino una **referencia** a la lista (un *puntero* en C/C++).

Si bien la lista va cambiando de **contenido**, no va cambiando de **identidad**; es siempre la misma lista.

#### Solución

Crear una nueva lista para cada jugador. Basta mover la creación de `lista_aux` dentro del `for`, al mismo nivel que la creación del jugador:

```
   def repartir_fihas(self):
        jugadoress = []
        n = 28  # número de elementos que deseas seleccionar
        seq = range(28)  # secuencia de elementos para elegir (en este caso, los números del 0 al 28)
        aleatorio = random.sample(seq, n)
        lista = self.crear_partida()
        for u in range(0, 4):
            lista_aux = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
            for i in range(0, 7):
                operacion = u * 7 + i

               lista_aux[i] = lista[aleatorio[operacion]]

            playeer = self.informacion(u)

            jugadoraux = jugador(playeer[0], playeer[1], playeer[2],
                                 lista_aux)  # creo un objeto jugador con una lista de fichas
            jugadoress.append(jugadoraux)  # creo un arreglo con 4 objetos del tipo jugador

        return jugadoress
```

Comment: Gracias lo intentaré